# Define artifact finalName in Hudson on Maven project

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson

I am unable to edit pom.xml. Is there a way to define final name of the maven artifact built by Hudson, something like this

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${timestamp}</finalName>
```

Since mvn -DfinalName="xxx" on command line does not seem to work. 
I am looking for Hudon/Jenkins feature to achieve this as well, or modifying settings.xml in maven repo. Basically any method except editing pom.xml

Comment: which plugin you use for build? plz show pom.xml

Comment: The thing is I want my solution to be pom.xml content independent. I will have many maven projects, whose pom files i cannot edit or even see. That's why I am looking for a general solution using Hudson or a command line

Comment: but without that, it will be hard. you need to know plugin name, so you could use it's parameter. some plugin use param finalName, some other - not

Comment: that's what I wanted to know: so there's no way to define artifact naming format without diving into pom contents, is that right?

Comment: my bet is - yes, it's nearly impossible, without looking into pom

Comment: I was hoping maybe Hudson has a plugin or a feature to manipulate already built artifact and rename it. Ok thanks anyways

Comment: Yeah. Probably Jenkins/Hudson have this feature. Update your question to ask it explicitly.

Comment: Can you explain what the purpose of this is? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I 'm gonna have several jobs on Hudson, every one of them will check out project from remote SVN repositories. I cannot edit pom files that are not mine. But I still need to define the artifact name format when Hudson builds these projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could have a second build step (execute shell or windows batch) to simply rename the artifacts. Obviously, this will forego the automatic maven module artifacting, but are you using that? If not, just archive the file with post-build actions directly on Jenkins or repository of choice.

Second, the moment you check out the files from SVN, you **do have access** to modify them in your local workspace. Just don't commit them back to repository.

You could run a regex replace to look for `<fileName>.*</filename>` and replace with whatever you want.

Comment: shell script is also one solution. I am planning to to use ant task to inject some lines to the pom using xslt. thanks for suggestions